# C# webrequest httpwebrequest issue

Tags: c#, .net, http, http-post, webrequest

I need to make a (new web request) because I am using threading in this function and it holds when I don't type var request = new ***;

`webrequest t = new webrequest();  //not webrequest tt = webrequest.create("");`

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide`: false console: true babel: false -->`

<!-- language: lang-C# -->

    public static void Change()
            {
                try
                    {
                      
                        var x = new request().t1(url);
                        x.Method = "POST";
                        x.Headers.Add("Authorization", "value";
                        x.ContentType="application/json";
                        String PostData = "jsonstring";
                        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PostData);
                        try
                        {
                            using (var stream = x.GetRequestStream())
                            {
                                ttt++;
                                Console.WriteLine($"Request num {ttt} sent");
                                Console.WriteLine($"Befor ms for {ttt}" +DateTime.Now.Ticks);
                                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                                Console.WriteLine($"after ms for {ttt}" +DateTime.Now.Ticks);
                                stream.Flush();
                                stream.Close();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e);
                        }
                        var response = (HttpWebResponse)x.GetResponse();
                        Console.WriteLine((int)response.StatusCode);
                        catch(Exception r)
                        {
                             Console.WriteLine(r);
                        }
                      }
                    }
 public class request
    {
        public WebRequest t1(string s)
        {
            return WebRequest.Create(s);
        }
    }

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: You would have to create a class that inherits the webRequest.  You cannot call the constructor new webrequest.  You will get an error.

Comment: i created a class and made a func called getwebrequest that returns a webrequest and used the class `someclass t = new someclass();` and then called the func `var x = t.getwebrequest();` and still the same thing i am running 10 threads and only 2 request sent and other threads waiting till the first 2 threads finshed

Comment: i tried to use the xnet lib and it worked i run 10 threads and the 10 threads starting, but some future in xnet is not the the system.net lib adn specifically in the webrequest class so i am forced to use the system.net lib , btw i searched for a libraries that has the future i want i didn't found

Comment: I may be the server than is not sending a response.  So you are waiting for the response before sending another request.  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and see when server is responding.

Comment: im my case the object is to send requests and then get the response from the server
i attched the code up
this func called by multiple threads and only 2 threads running and others waiting till first 2 finshed